# Can anyone suggest me resource to practice my German A2/b1? more like worksheet or handbooks where i can really practice Thanks

Tags: resource

Can anyone suggest me resource to practice my German A2/b1? more like worksheet or handbooks where i can really practice

Answer (score 0):

these sites have many exercises to boost your vocabulary and grammar: http://nthuleen.com/teach.html
www.lingolia.com/